# Print from the frontend using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm currently working on an AngularJS project and I would like to print option selected on a drop down list together with input data that has been entered by the user without using the backend. How can this be done using AngularJS? Any help?

Comment: A third button is required. It's a button like a submit button that returns the value selected on a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you wanted something like Prefix + Name, her https://jsfiddle.net/datachand/szc550yb/3/

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl as vm">
   <select ng-model="vm.prefix">
     <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
     <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" ng-model="vm.name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
   <button ng-click="vm.submit()">
      Send
   </button>
</div>
```

A controller is needed at any case, even if it's empty:

```
angular.module('app', []);

function UserCtrl ($log) {
    $log.log('UserCtrl');
    var vm = this;

    vm.submit = function () {
        $log.log(vm.prefix, vm.name);
        $window.location.href = "https://towhateverurl" + "?prefix=" + vm.prefix +"&name=" + vm.name;
}

UserCtrl.$inject = ['$log'];

angular.module('app').controller('UserCtrl', UserCtrl);
```

I hope this is what, is required.

Comment: Not exactly. A third button like submit is expected where the both values entered can be received and then returned on a new page.

Comment: I think you can add a button with `ng-click="vm.submit()"` and write a `this.submit = function () {  }` in your controller and redirect the page by `window.location = ...` with `this.name` and `this.prefix`.

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't seem to work. Could you please show me a sample code of what you are saying?

Comment: please, I added a comment yesterday. Could you please check it out? Thanks.